# MySQL Query with LARGE number of records gets Killed

Tags: mysql, command-line-interface

I run the following query from my shell :

```
    mysql -h my-host.net -u myuser -p -e "SELECT component_id, parent_component_id FROM myschema.components comp INNER JOIN my_second_schema.component_parents related_comp ON comp.id = related_comp.component_id ORDER BY component_id;" > /tmp/IT_component_parents.txt
```

The query runs for a LONG time and then gets KILLED.

However if I add `LIMIT 1000`, then the query runs till the end and output is written in file.

I further investigated and found (using COUNT(*)) that the total number of records that would be returned are 239553163.

Some information about my server is here:

MySQL 5.5.27

```
    +----------------------------+----------+
    | Variable_name              | Value    |
    +----------------------------+----------+
    | connect_timeout            | 10       |
    | delayed_insert_timeout     | 300      |
    | innodb_lock_wait_timeout   | 50       |
    | innodb_rollback_on_timeout | OFF      |
    | interactive_timeout        | 28800    |
    | lock_wait_timeout          | 31536000 |
    | net_read_timeout           | 30       |
    | net_write_timeout          | 60       |
    | slave_net_timeout          | 3600     |
    | wait_timeout               | 28800    |
    +----------------------------+----------+
```

Here's STATE of the query as I monitored :

```
    copying to tmp table on disk
    sorting results
    sending data
    writing to net
    sending data
    writing to net
    sending data
    writing to net
    sending data ...
    KILLED
```

Any guesses what's wrong here ?

Answer (score 22):

The mysql client probably runs out of memory.

Use the --quick option to not buffer results in memory.

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong is that you are returning 239 553 163 rows of data! Don't be surprised it it takes a lot of time to process. Actually, the longest part might very well be sending the result set back to your client.

Reuduce the result set (do you really need all these rows?). Or try to output the data in smaller batches:

```
mysql -h my-host.net -u myuser -p -e "SELECT ... LIMIT 10000, 0" >> dump.txt
mysql -h my-host.net -u myuser -p -e "SELECT ... LIMIT 10000, 10000" >> dump.txt
```

Comment: I already had that thought to break the result set into smaller pieces. But trying to see if there's a workaround to get that done in one shot :)
Yes, I need all the rows. It is required by the task that I'm trying to accomplish. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @ManmohanBishnoi Are you connecting to a shared host, or do you own the DB server? In the first case, the host could very well have implemented something that kills long queries (I think that's what the "KILLED" notice means). Shared hosts probably (hopefully ;) implement such things to protect their systems agains DoS-like attacks.

Comment: It's an Amazon RDS large Instance.
I have run LONG queries for INSERT/UPDATE with similar number of records. so I guess I have have to ask my DBA for this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean 8 hours when you say a long time, the value `28800` for your `wait_timeout` causes the connection to drop with no further activity in 28,800 seconds, i.e. 8 hours. If you can't optimize the statement to run in less than 8 hours, you should increase this value.

See [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) for further information on the `wait_timeout` variable.

The `interactive_timeout` variable is used for interactive client connections, so if you run long queries from an interactive session, that's the one you need look at.

Comment: The query gets killed after 3100 seconds. so I guess the values are sufficient.

Comment: As RandomSeed suggests, there could be an external `KILL` command run by an admin or a job; a regularly scheduled event might run that checks long-running queries (if it's always 3100 seconds, or if it's 3100 plus or minus 180 seconds or some other similar value, that could be a giveaway), running something like `SELECT id FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST WHERE TIME>3000 AND Command != 'Sleep'` and killing IDs it gets back

Comment: there are other queries that take around 13000 seconds to complete and they are working as expected, so It is some other parameter/variable we have to change to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to utilize [OUTFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-into.html) mechanizm if you are going to dump large amounts of data. That or mysql_dump will be much more efficient (and OUTFILE got the benefit of not locking-down the table).

Comment: The user I have credentials for does not have FILE permissions so OUTFILE will not be useful here.

Comment: Then this is something to confront with hosting provider as this is about the best option to select large batches of data to a CSV or other format.

Answer (score 0):

You said in a comment that your MySQL instance is on RDS. This means you can't be running the query from the same host, since you can't log into an RDS host. I guess you might be doing this query over the WAN from your local network.

You're most likely having trouble because of a slow network. Your process state frequently showing "writing to net" makes me think this is your bottleneck.

Your bottleneck might also be the sorting. Your sort is writing to a temp table, and that can take a long time for a result set that large. Can you skip the ORDER BY?

Even so, I wouldn't expect the query to be killed even if it runs for 3100 seconds or more. I wonder if your DBA has some periodic job killing long-running queries, like [pt-kill](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-kill.html). Ask your DBA.

To reduce network transfer time, you could try using the compression protocol. You can use the `--compress` or `-C` flags to the mysql client for this (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_compress)

On a slow network, compression can help. For example, read about some comparisons here: https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/12/20/large-result-sets-vs-compression-protocol/

Another alternative is to run the query from an EC2 spot instance running in the same AZ as your RDS instance. The network between those two instances will be a lot faster, so it won't delay your data transfer. Save the query output to a file on the EC2 spot instance.

Once the query result is saved on your EC2 instance, you can download it to your local machine, using `scp` or something, which should be more tolerant of slow networks.

Comment: The query was run between EC2 and RDS. The ORDER BY was necessary for this query. However a lot has changed since I posted this question some time back. We have a complete new database running on PostgreSQL.

Comment: Ah. I should check the dates of questions more carefully. This popped up in my feed 2 days ago, but it's four years ago that you asked it.